# How to unit test javascript embedded in razor view with visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

Is it possible to unit test javascript that is embedded in a razor(.cshtml) view with Visual Studio Test Explorer?  I briefly looked at Chutzpah, but it looks like the javascript has to be separated into its own file.

Comment: Separate out. It's the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference it some way in Chutzpah. They only way to do that is by putting it in a separate file.

```
/// <reference path="yourjsfiletotest.js" />
```

Tight-coupling JS and HTML code is no way to write testable code.

Comment: this is the first mvc project I worked on with js embedded in razor views...and a ton of the views have js embedded.  I kind of like it, I know exactly what js a page uses.  There is also a main js file that is common to all the views.  Thanks for your answer.